# How to multiply a standard normal RV times a uniform{-1.1} RV?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm not really sure how to even start this question. I know how to get the pdfs of both, but don't get what it equals when you multiply them together, especially since they have different ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Call $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim U[-1,1]$, $X,Y$ independent with respective densities $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$. We want to compute the density $f_U(u)$ of $U$.

Define the random vector $(U,V):=g(X,Y)=(XY,Y)$ (where component $x$ is what we want, and component $y$ is untouched.

Then, the formula for the density of $(U,V)$ is as follows:

$$f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_{X,Y}(g^{-1}(u,v))|\det J(g^{-1}(u,v))|$$
where $J(g^{-1}(u,v))$ denotes the Jacobian matrix of $g^{-1}(u,v)$.

Once you find the density of the random vector $(U,V)$, you just need to integrate over $v$ to obtain the marginal density of $U$, that means the density of $U=XY$.

Ask if you need more help. Good luck!