# the characteristic function of this distribution is equal to 0 everywhere except at the origin, mistake?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

I wanted to compute the characteristic function of the distribution in question here:

[How to multiply a standard normal RV times a uniform{-1.1} RV?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669842/how-to-multiply-a-standard-normal-rv-times-a-uniform-1-1-rv/669912#669912)

Let $X$ be standard $N(0,1)$,  $Y$ be Uniform $[-1,1]$, consider $Z=XY$, then, for $t\neq 0$

$E[e^{itXY}] = E[E[e^{itXY}|Y]]= E\phi(itX)$

where $\phi$ is the uniform distribution's MGF, that is

$E[e^{itXY}] = E[\frac{e^{itX}-e^{-itX}}{2it} ]=0$

where is the mistake? This is extremely alarming, because the moment generating function is 0 except at the origin and this argument hold for all value of $\sigma$! surely they are not the same distribution!

Comment: You should condition on $X$ (not $Y$). Need to remove $i$ in $\phi(itX)$. And you are assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Also, $\frac{e^{itX}-e^{-itX}}{2it}$ should be $\frac{e^{itX}-e^{-itX}}{2itX}$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I think we did it! I actually struggled making your observation. Thank you.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland that was careless...

Comment: @Lost1 Everybody makes mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, in your second equality, you are stating that:

$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\mathrm e^{itXY}|Y \right] $$

is some function of $X$.

As you condition on the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(Y)$,  this conditional expectation must be a measurable function of $Y$.

For example, in the convenient case where $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we have:
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\mathrm e^{itXY}|Y \right]  = f(Y),$$
where $f(y) = \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathrm e^{itXy}\right] = \phi_X(ty)$.  Under the same independence assumption, we also have: $$ \mathbb{E}\left[\mathrm e^{itXY}|X \right]  = g(X),$$
where $g(x) = \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathrm e^{itxY}\right] = \phi_Y(tx)$.

Now, $$\phi_Y(s) = \frac{\mathrm e^{is} - \mathrm e^{-is}}{2is} .$$

And, **as noted by Byron Schmuland** (see comments),

$$g(X) = \phi_Y(tX) = \frac{\mathrm e^{itX} - \mathrm e^{-itX}}{2itX}, $$

not $$ \frac{\mathrm e^{itX} - \mathrm e^{-itX}}{2it}.$$

Comment: Oh... I see....